# Creating new instances with google-cloud-compute client library returns forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

**Background:**

I am creating tooling to manage development specific deployments to GCE. We are using some static instances and some that should follow a branch from github.

**The issue:**
I am currently using google cloud client java library to achieve control over GCE. This works great from localhost using a service account but not from an actual server using the same service account key-file it returns

```json
  {
    "error": {
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Required 'compute.zones.list' permission for 'projects/my-project'",
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "Required 'compute.zones.list' permission for 'projects/my-project",
          "domain": "global",
          "reason": "forbidden"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The service account has the `'compute.*'` permission set.

The service account is set with gcloud auth set-active-service-account and ADC by exporting GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS following [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc)

I hav tried setting scopes for a user, changing and adding permissions and roles to the service account. This is returned when trying to revoke ADC:

```bash
$ gcloud auth application-default revoke
Application Default Credentials have not been set up, nothing to revoke.
```

What am I missing with regards to using service accounts?

Comment: Are you actually getting this error 'projects/my-project' ? or did you edit? If you did not edit make sure to use project ID and not project name

Comment: Yes. I did edit , the poject is an actual project id and not the name.